# Как лучше хранить дерево объектов с изменениями связей между ними во времени

Tags: структуры-данных

Надо хранить дерево во-времени. Например возьмем дерево структуры подразделений организации. Проблема в том что эта структура изменяется во времени, причем появляются новые подразделения, какие-то исчезают, переподчиняются и т.д. Как лучше хранить такие данные - в какой  структуре данных? Надо получать структуру организации на какой-то момент времени, какие подразделения являются подчиненными в этот момент и т.д.

Comment: обычное же дело, реляционная бд, таблица с подразделениями и таблица со связями, каждая из которых дополнительно содержит интервал ее существования

Comment: А неважно на самом деле. Главное - забыть слова "удалить" и "изменить". Появилось новое - добавляем. Удалилось существовавшее - помечаем недействительным. Изменилось - старое помечаем недействительным и добавляем действительное новое. А так да - любая СУБД, и структура, ориентированная именно на хранение и обработку дерева.